# server side push notifications,how to generate cerificates in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5

First of all thanks for your attention. The escenario here is that I need to send the same PUSH notification to thousands of devices. I've been reading the Apple documentation regarding to this topic, how to generate .p12 certificate in pushnotifications

Answer (score 0):

**To Generate a Push Certificate for server Side Follow these simple steps**

**Step 1:** Log-in to the iPhone Developer Program Portal.

**Step 2:** Choose App IDs from the menu on the right.

**Step 3:** Create an App ID without a wildcard. For example 3L223ZX9Y3.com.hello.test

**Step 4:** Click the Configure link next to this App ID and then click on the button to start the wizard to generate a new Development Push SSL Certificate

**Step 5:** Download this certificate and double click on aps_developer_identity.cer to import it into your Keychain.

**Step 6:**  Launch Keychain Assistant (located in Application, Utilities or search for it with Spotlight) and click on My Certificates on the left.

**Step 7:**  Expand Apple Development Push Services and select Apple Development Push Services AND your private key (just under Apple Development Push Services).

**Step 8:** Right-click and choose "Export 2 elements..." and save as server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.p12 (don't type a password).

**Step 9:** Open Terminal and change directory to location used to save server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.p12 and convert the PKCS12 certificate bundle into PEM format using this command (press enter when asked for Import Password):

```
openssl pkcs12 -in server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.p12 -out server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem -nodes -clcerts
```